# How to use a different dpkg status file to autoinstall packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am moving from a 2TB hard drive to a 4TB SSD.  I have installed 22.04LTS on the new SSD.  The complete list of non-SNAP packages I have is in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` .  How do I force `apt` to install just the packages from the old `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file that have not been installed with the new 22.04LTS ? I have saved the old `/var/lib/dpkg/status` on the new drive in a non-systems directory owned by me. Obviously, I can do this manually one by one.  If I do a `diff` between the old and new `/var/lib/dpkg/status` files, I presumably can find the files missing from the new `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.  Is there a way to automate the process (e.g., switches to apt or any other package installer to only add the packages that are not on the new system)?

Comment: Yes you do them one at a time there are too many dependencies to do it any other way.

Comment: If you can boot old install, it is easy to export list of apps. And that should be part of a normal backup.  Even if you have full list, it only installs those missing. Or you can export list of manually added. `apt-mark showmanual | sort -u` https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474107&p=14091927#post14091927

Comment: Another option is to use https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80520 on the older system, which provides you the list of packages present that were NOT installed by the Ubuntu installer (i.e. installed by you later).

Comment: I am running the 2TB 22.04LTS now, with the 4TB 22.04 LTS SSD physically attached to a SATA to USB converter, accessed through a USB mount, and doing  as root in a terminal under MATE `cp -pra` of various non-systems directories, such as `/opt` or `/usr/local` to the 4TB 22.04 LTS SSD.  What are the specific steps to do what you suggest, to wit:  it is easy to export list of apps. And that should be part of a normal backup. Even if you have full list, it only installs those missing. ?  I assume that this is done in a terminal application as root .